# PHP - Prev & Next links to scroll through array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code but its not displaying the Prev & Next links?

```
$path = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

 foreach ($url as $key => $page)
 {
    if ($path == $page)
    {
          if ($prev = $url[$key-1])
                $prev_link = "<a href=\"{$prev}\">prev</a>";
          if ($next = $url[$key+1])
                $next_link = "<a href=\"{$next}\">next</a>";
    }
    else
    { }
    }
}

echo $prev_link . ' - ' . $next_link;
```

Comment: Why do you have an extra `}`. Is it a typo.?

Comment: And what do you mean by `if ($prev = $url[$key-1])?` Did you mean `==`?

Comment: Forgot to add this to the code at the top... $url = array('index.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php', 'page5.php', 'page6.php', 'page7.php', 'page8.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//i used my own urls from existing project, you may use your own
$url = array('/english/take-credit/1',
        '/english/take-credit/2', '/english/take-credit/3', '/english/take-credit/4',
        '/english/take-credit/5', '/english/take-credit/6', '/english/take-credit/7', '/english/take-credit/8');

//i use a framework so $path = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); was returning always "index.php"
    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$prev_link = $next_link = 'no more pages';

foreach ($url as $key => $page) {
    if ($path == $page) {
        if (isset($url[$key - 1]))
            $prev_link = "<a href=\"{$url[$key - 1]}\">prev</a>";
        if (isset($url[$key + 1]))
            $next_link = "<a href=\"{$url[$key + 1]}\">next</a>";
    }
}

echo $prev_link . ' - ' . $next_link;
```

This code was tested on a live project and it works, if you have more difficulties you may add a comment.

Comment: Forgot to add this for $url: $url = array('index.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php', 'page5.php', 'page6.php', 'page7.php', 'page8.php');

Comment: Where do $prev and $next get set?

Comment: I added: $prev_link=$next_link='no more pages'; - now it displays "no more pages"... hmmm seems like its not getting the array?